# Bounds on remainder term of power series of elementary functions

Tags: ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, special-functions, computer-algebra

This is mainly a question about the remainder term of power series for elementary functions.

I'm very interested in aspects of calculating or computing elementary operations and functions, by which I mean:

- trigonometric: $\sin$, $\cos$, $\tan$
- inverse trig.: $\sin^{-1}$, $\cos^{-1}$, $\tan^{-1}$
- log and exponential: $\ln$, $\exp$
- hyperbolic: $\sinh$, $\cosh$, $\tanh$
- inverse hyp.: $\sinh^{-1}$, $\cosh^{-1}$, $\tanh^{-1}$
- powers, reciprocation, $\sqrt{\ \ \ }$

perhaps also:

- gamma function: $\Gamma$
- and a few other important functions

There are many contexts (of calculation). For example:

- real *versus* complex arguments
- known, fixed precision *versus* variable precision
- numerical *versus* symbolic

There are many approaches and techniques available too. For example:

- power series expansions and polynomial approximations
- use of relationships between the functions
- use of periodic or similar properties to shrink the domain
- lookup tables and interpolation
- CORDIC (used within some hand calculators I believe)
- *exact* methods
- interval or other error-tracking methods

Some good references to certain aspects include:

- Digital Library of Mathematical Functions: [Elementary Functions](http://dlmf.nist.gov/4)
- Chee-Keng Yap, [Fundamental problems of algorithmic algebra](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=YzjvQ-TSQ4gC&dq=polynomials+inauthor:yap&hl=en&ei=1cxpTPK3Kti4jAeOyqTUBA&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=10&ved=0CGIQ6AEwCQ)
- Behrooz Parhami, [Computer Arithmetic: Algorithms and Hardware Designs](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Computer-Arithmetic-Algorithms-Hardware-Designs/dp/0195125835/ref=sr_1_2?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1282002469&sr=1-2)

**The main gap in my knowledge is in finding bounds for the error or remainder term in partial power series expansions of certain of the above functions. Some are fairly simple to determine, whilst others seem to be awkward.**

**Any pointers on this matter would be much appreciated.**

Likewise for any further references on any other aspects of or techniques for calculating elementary functions.

Comment: Two things: 1. you might be interested in this book: http://personales.unican.es/segurajj/book/ ; and 2. don't just confine yourself to implementing things with only power series, they are almost always only effective within a restricted range of arguments (unless your functions of interest satisfy useful reduction formulae). As might be already obvious to you, the easiest bound for the truncation error of a power series is the first neglected term.

Comment: You've listed a huge load of references, but not said in detail exactly why these are not enough to solve your problems. I think a *detailed* question would be helpful; can you give a particular power series for which you cannot determine a good estimate for the remainder, by any of the standard methods you've listed?

Comment: First of all, thanks to all for the comments and answers; all good and all appreciated.

Comment: @J. Mangaldan (2) are there any particular methods beyond power series and the few others I mentioned above that you would particularly recommend I consider? Do you have a reference for the use of the first neglected term as a bound on the remainder? What are the conditions for that to hold? Thanks again.

Comment: @Zen Harper: My question was vague partly intentionally (I am very pleased with the responses), and partly as I'm only an _amateur_ mathematician. As a particular case: the terms of the expansion of sin are simple because the sequence of derivatives remains simple. On the other hand, the terms of the expansion of tan seem to become very unwieldy; the closed form is superficially simple, but involves the Bernoulli numbers, which are somewhat erratic. I expect I'm missing something quite simple. In saying that, I wasn't fishing for a specific solution so much as some _leads_. Thanks again.

Comment: The other tricks applicable to the computation of special functions are in the book I linked to, you really should get a copy. Quadrature with a suitable integral representation of your function, and the use of continued fractions, are two of the often neglected but otherwise viable methods for computing special functions. Asymptotic series are useful when considering large arguments.

On the subject of using the first neglected term, this is the usual approach taken since Taylor series are only used for arguments "near" (how "near" depends on the function) the point of expansion...

Comment: ...and also since other bounds, like Lagrange's or Cauchy's, require the computation of high-order derivatives, which is not always feasible. At the very least, this works for alternating series.

Answer (score 6):

These bounds you are looking for can be obtained from *majorant series*.  What you seek is implemented in the [Dynamic Dictionary of Mathematical Functions](http://ddmf.msr-inria.inria.fr/ddmf); [Bruno Salvy](http://algo.inria.fr/salvy/) gave a very nice [talk](http://algo.inria.fr/salvy/Talks/aisc.pdf) on this topic at [CICM 2010](http://cicm2010.cnam.fr/index.html) in early July.

For the *guaranteed numerics* aspect, the expert is [Marc Mezzarobba](http://www.normalesup.org/~mezzarobba/), a PhD student of Bruno's.  On that page, see the links to **NumGfun** (software, presentation and paper) for all the details you would ever want on the topic.

Answer (score 5):

> finding bounds for the error or remainder term in partial power series expansions

I think you want the [Euler-Maclaurin Summation formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Maclaurin_formula#Asymptotic_expansion_of_sums).  That bounds the remainder terms, although it would require knowing the closed form of the integral representation of the function you are calculating.

$ \sum_{n=a}^b f(n) \sim \int_a^b f(x)\,dx + \frac{f(a)+f(b)}{2} + \sum_{k=1}^\infty \,\frac{B_{2k}}{(2k)!}\left(f^{(2k-1)}(b)-f^{(2k-1)}(a)\right) $

The paper by [Apostol "Elementary view of Euler-Maclaurin" AMM vol 106 (1999) pp. 409-418](http://www.jstor.org/stable/2589145)  is very accessible.

The following papers/books may also be helpful

1. R.P. Boas "[Estimating
   Remainders](http://www.jstor.org/stable/2690143)." Math. Mag. 51,
   pp 83-89, (1978)
2. http://www.tricki.org/article/Estimating_sums
3. Bridger and Frampton [Bounding Power
   Series Remainders](http://www.jstor.org/stable/2691205) Math. Mag. 71 (1998), pp. 204-207
4. Sofo. [Computational Techniques for
   the Summation of Series](http://www.springer.com/mathematics/analysis/book/978-0-306-47805-5)
5. Ross.  [Methods of Summation](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0007BHA3C)
6. Davis.  [Summation of Series.](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0007FQCIW)